# Are comparison format and and or satisfy the PSR12 standard?

Tags: php, psr-12

Considering this fragment of code

```
if ($x > 0 and $x !== 1)   {
 return;
}
```

Is the comparison operator expressed as `and` and `or` rather than `&&` and `||` considered acceptable according to the PSR-12 standard?

Comment: Why not run a checker to see what happens?